# How does electron-rebuild control the node_module_version of a rebuild?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, electron-builder, node-serialport

I am testing the usage of Electron and *serialport* modules…

When I run the `electron .` command, this error shows up:

```
The module '…/teste3/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node' 
   was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 79. 
   This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73.
```

I ran the rebuild command (node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild) and the 79 got downgraded to 50, and with it, my problem continues.

I tried to change my *node* version and rebuild, but the 50 still the same.

The second NODE_MODULE_VERSION (73) is based on Electron version. I changed Electron version, rebuilt and this version changed too.

The first NODE_MODULE_VERSION (79) is based on the build of serialport (I think).

My questions are:

- What my first NODE_MODULE_VERSION (79) build is based on?
- Why did it downgrade to 50 and not to any other version?
- What tells to Electron-rebuild which NODE_MODULE_VERSION it should use?
- Is this even the way it works or am I totally lost?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

cd node_modules/path_to_module && node-gyp rebuild --target=4.2.0 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron,, replace with the path to the module also the electron version.